# Using an anonymous listener object inside the Timer class

Tags: java

Can it be done? I tried doing this, but it gives a compilation error:

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    }
});
```

Here's the entire code for reference

---

Full Code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Scratch {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Moving Rectangle");
        frame.setSize(1000,700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            }

        });
        Timer t = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

I need to type something as my question is mostly code.

Comment: what is the compilation error ?

Comment: Yes, it can be done quite simply, and you almost got it!

Comment: It says that the constructor is undefined. :(

Comment: `It says that the constructor is undefined` - makes no sense to me because I copied and pasted the code and it compiled fine. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. You muse have other problems, maybe a missing import statement. So basically create a main() method and add the code to the method and get to compile.

Comment: Ok, here's my entire code:

Answer (score 1):

> but it gives a compilation error:

When you ask a question post the error so we don't have to guess.

When I added your code to an empty main() method I got the following because I had a lot of standard import statements in the test class:

```
Main.java:21: error: reference to Timer is ambiguous, both class java.util.Timer in java.util and class javax.swing.Timer in javax.swing match
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
```

The solution can be to use:

```
javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
```

to avoid confusion.

Edit:

Did you look at my solution above? Notice how I'm using a javax.swing.Timer?

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

Don't use java.util.Timer. With Swing you need to use the Swing Timer, so the code is executed on the EDT.

Instead use:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, the actual error is that it says that the constructor is undefined. :(

Comment: @KaneWilliamson, see the edit. This is why we need the `SSCCE`. To understand the context of your code and the compiler message.